# Label properties modified with jQuery and Java code don't save it. in ZK

Tags: java, jquery, dynamic, drag-and-drop, zk

I'm creating dynamics labels and set it top and left properties,
and I modified the top and left properties dynamically with Drag and drop of jquery, 
but when I try retrieve these top and left properties from label  I get the originals properties the label and I want the new properties to work in my java code.

Sorry here is my code
main.zul - Jquery Part

```
<script>
function dragEvent(label, section){
    var txtNom = jq('$txtNom');
    var txtX = jq('$txtX');
    var txtY = jq('$txtY');
    var txtW = jq('$txtWidth');
    var txtH = jq('$txtHeight');


    label.draggable({
        start: function()
        {

        },
        drag: function(e,u)
        {
            txtNom.val(label.text());
            txtX.val(label.offset().left-section.offset().left);
            txtY.val(label.offset().top-section.offset().top);
            txtW.val(label.width());
            txtH.val(label.height());
        },
        stop: function(e,u)
        {
            txtNom.val(label.text());
            txtX.val(label.offset().left-section.offset().left);
            txtY.val(label.offset().top-section.offset().top);
            txtW.val(label.width());
            txtH.val(label.height());
        }
    });

     }

  function bindEventLabel(lblId,trSeccion)
  {
      var label = jq('$'+lblId+'');
      var section = jq('$'+trSeccion+'');
      dragEvent(label,section);
  }
```

Main.java

```
    @Listen("onClick = #btnGenRep")
public void onGenerateReport()
{
    String file = "C:\\Users\\hgarza\\Desktop\\Reportes\\reporte.jrxml";
    File src = new File(file);
    JasperDesign desgin = null;
    try {
        desgin = (JasperDesign) JRXmlLoader.load(src);
    } catch (JRException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Grid gridtemp = null;
    for(Component comp : dEBody.getChildren())
    {
        if(comp instanceof Grid)
        {
            gridtemp = (Grid) comp;
            break;
        }
    }


    for(Component rowss : gridtemp.getChildren())
    {
        if(rowss instanceof Rows)
            {
            Rows rowsTemp = (Rows)rowss;
                for(Component roww : rowsTemp.getChildren())
                {
                if(roww instanceof Row){
                        Row rowTemp = (Row)roww;
                for(Component labell : rowTemp.getChildren())
                {
                Label lbl = labell instanceof Label ?  (Label) labell : null;
                System.out.println(lbl.getValue());
                if(lbl.getId().equals("sTitulo"))
                    {
                        JRDesignStaticText lTitle = (JRDesignStaticText)desgin.getTitle().getElementByKey("sTitulo");
                        lTitle.setX(new Integer(lbl.getLeft().split("px")[0]));
                        lTitle.setY(new Integer(lbl.getTop().split("px")[0]));
                    }

                if(lbl.getId().equals("sSubtitulo"))
                    {
                    JRDesignStaticText lSubTitle = (JRDesignStaticText)desgin.getPageHeader().getElementByKey("sSubtitulo");
                        lSubTitle.setX(new Integer(lbl.getLeft().split("px")[0]));
                        lSubTitle.setY(new Integer(lbl.getTop().split("px")[0]));
                    }

                if(lbl.getId().equals("sDetalles"))
                    {
                    JRDesignStaticText lDetalle = (JRDesignStaticText)desgin.getColumnHeader().getElementByKey("sDetalles");
                        lDetalle.setX(new Integer(lbl.getLeft().split("px")[0]));
                        lDetalle.setY(new Integer(lbl.getTop().split("px")[0]));
                    }

                if(lbl.getId().equals("pNombre"))
                    {
                        JRBand detail = desgin.getDetailSection().getBands()[0];
                        JRDesignTextField param = (JRDesignTextField) detail.getElementByKey("pNombre");
                        param.setX(new Integer(lbl.getLeft().split("px")[0]));
                        param.setY(new Integer(lbl.getTop().split("px")[0]));

                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I read that I have update the properties from the client side but I don't know how doing it

Comment: Please provide an example of the code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

problem is that you change value on client (browser) side and you do not send notification to server side that something is changed. On first though I will do following :

change JS and add notification

```
stop: function(e,u)
{
  txtNom.val(label.text());
  txtX.val(label.offset().left-section.offset().left);
  txtY.val(label.offset().top-section.offset().top);
  txtW.val(label.width());
  txtH.val(label.height());
  <!-- ADDED -->
  var message = "X:" + label.offset().left-section.offset().left + ";Y:label.offset().top-section.offset().top";
  zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$('$myLableID'), "onCoordinateChange", {'' : message}, {toServer:true}));
}
```

set up a label as follows

```
<label id="myLableID" onCoordinateChange="@command('doChangeLabel', v=event.data)" value="Movable label"/>
```

and in a ViewModel add

```
@Command
public void doChangeLabel(@BindingParam("v") String value) {
  // parse your message received from JS (X:213213;Y:23423423)
}
```

And this shall work